# Working in Visual Studio in Immediate Window: error CS0103: The name 'g' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2022, immediate-window

In the immediate window I create a new class with the name g.
When I ask for the content of g, the error occurs.

Groepsreis g = new Groepsreis ("London", 10, 125.1);
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
?g
error CS0103: The name 'g' does not exist in the current context

On some moments the content of g was visible, but I don't know what makes it work and what causes the error.
Can someone help? Can someone explain why this error happens and sometimes not?